# JS: Use loop to individually disable multiple checkbox's?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it's possible to use a loop to loop through the following JS as a function instead of writing an individual script for each checkbox ID?

I'm not too good with JS, I'm familiar with PHP foreach loops though - so I'm not completely blind, but obviously not the same thing. I'd like to stay away from jQuery as well.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
<input type="text" id="in1" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
<input type="text" id="in2" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3">
<input type="text" id="in3" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4">
<input type="text" id="in4" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5">
<input type="text" id="in5" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb6">
<input type="text" id="in6" disabled>

<script>
document.getElementById('cb1').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in1').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('cb2').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in2').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('cb3').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in3').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('cb4').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in4').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('cb5').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in5').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('cb6').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('in6').disabled = !this.checked;
};
</script>
```

The above code currently works as is (just bulky)...

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6j7dddzv/

---

My current markup is actually like this, FYI:

```
<div class="extra-padding options-parts">
    <h4><b>Replacement Parts</b></h4>
    <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_hoses" id="parts-cb1" value="1"><label for="parts-hoses">Vinyl Tubing<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_hoses_n" id="parts-in1" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_pumps" id="parts-cb2" value="1"><label for="parts-pumps">Pumps<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_pumps_n" id="parts-in2" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_lights" id="parts-cb3" value="1"><label for="parts-lights">Light Bulbs<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_lights_n" id="parts-in3" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_trans" id="parts-cb4" value="1"><label for="parts-trans">Transformers<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_trans_n" id="parts-in4" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_river" id="parts-cb5" value="1"><label for="parts-river">River Rocks<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_river_n" id="parts-in5" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-2">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="col-2-3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="parts_screen" id="parts-cb6" value="1"><label for="parts-screen">Mesh Divider<b>:</b></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1-3"><input name="parts_screen_n" id="parts-in6" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle with current markup: https://jsfiddle.net/mogjLxfd/1/

Comment: err, use a common *class* perhaps?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides thanks for commenting, could you expand on your idea? =)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, fair statement, I don't think I'm asking anyone to code on my behalf though - if the code is limited to working in a certain scenario but not for what I had intended for it to be used in then I'm not sure what good it can be as an answer to my question.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, if you're able to provide some more ideas or insight that would be great - if only you knew I've been working on this for about 4 hours lol. I can't stand JS (and I suck at it), I haven't been able to find a solid solution for this yet though. I don't care for downvoting or any of that.

Comment: There you go then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your second jsFiddle, we can derive the following, to enable/disable the boxes:

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
function getOnChange(i) {
  return function(){
    var inp = document.getElementById(boxes[i].id.replace(/cb/, 'in'));
    if(this.checked) {
      inp.disabled = false;
      inp.readOnly = false;
    } else {
      inp.disabled = true;
      inp.readOnly = true;
    }
  };
};
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length - 1; i++) {
  boxes[i].onchange = getOnChange(i);
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/w4ve2yzq for a working example...

Comment: I really like this, let me test out with my markup.

Comment: I don't think this solution is scalable.

Comment: @Matthew, you can also create that UI markup by looping on an array of some basic object [{name:'hoses' ... }] DO test the rendering though, as AKS may have a point on performance..

Comment: I agree, I don't see this as being scalable - but for what I'm doing it's not a big deal. It is what I asked for ironically haha

Comment: I just want it to work haha... https://jsfiddle.net/4vaazsnc/ my dev console is also throwing errors at `= !this.checked;`

Comment: You can't capture the current value of a loop variable for use in callback function, unless the variable is `let`ed and not `var`ed or you wrap the loop body with a IIFE `(function (i) { ... })(i);`.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, thanks, someone else has... I'd like to fix it :)
Does my new fiddle fix you thing?

Comment: I really appreciate it, @malix

Comment: No problem, it's what the site is for... Good luck!

Comment: Hey Malix,   hate to be a pain, just noticed the last check box isn't being checked... I'm going to check it out (there's a pun there lol) in the morning (it's just about 2am here now), just thought I'd let you know if you if you wanted to take a look. I'll be back in the morning though

Comment: i < boxes.length - 1... it seems to be the -1 that's the culprit here? It works by removing the -1. Would this cause any other issues?

Comment: I have other checkboxes on the page, they're disabling themselves by checking and unchecking them.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"][id^="parts-cb"]'); should do it

Comment: Ah! I see you fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get all the `checkbox` element and use `nextElementSibling` to get the next element of the current element.

`ATTRIBUTE^=VALUE` could be used to find the elements having attribute begins with specified value.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"]');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.disabled = !this.checked
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
<input type="text" id="in1" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
<input type="text" id="in2" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3">
<input type="text" id="in3" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4">
<input type="text" id="in4" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb5">
<input type="text" id="in5" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb6">
<input type="text" id="in6" disabled>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kjyqv2w3/)

**Edit:**

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"][id^="parts-cb"]');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input').disabled = !this.checked;
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="extra-padding options-parts">
  <h4><b>Replacement Parts</b></h4>
  <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_hoses" id="parts-cb1" value="1">
          <label for="parts-hoses">Vinyl Tubing<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_hoses_n" id="parts-in1" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_pumps" id="parts-cb2" value="1">
          <label for="parts-pumps">Pumps<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_pumps_n" id="parts-in2" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_lights" id="parts-cb3" value="1">
          <label for="parts-lights">Light Bulbs<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_lights_n" id="parts-in3" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_trans" id="parts-cb4" value="1">
          <label for="parts-trans">Transformers<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_trans_n" id="parts-in4" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row break-on-mobile collapse">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_river" id="parts-cb5" value="1">
          <label for="parts-river">River Rocks<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_river_n" id="parts-in5" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="col-2-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="parts_screen" id="parts-cb6" value="1">
          <label for="parts-screen">Mesh Divider<b>:</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-3">
          <input name="parts_screen_n" id="parts-in6" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1 – 20" disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/4vaazsnc/4/)

Comment: I updated my question to show my current markup, I'm not sure finding the next element would work?? Maybe I'm not understand it.

Comment: Initially I had marked this as correct, but it doesn't work with my markup at the moment. It can't find the items by way of next sibling - had to be from ID.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in HTML can and are very commonly used for grabbing the elements in groups in Javascript as well, not just CSS.

So, give the same class to all the checkboxes you want to target and then grab them using [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which will give you the DOM elements in an array you can iterate over.

You can then use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to target the next-immediate DOM element of each checkbox.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".top-checkbox");

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      this.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input class="top-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input type="text" disabled>
```

---

Note that [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) is not supported < IE9. It also necessitates that your `<input>` is *always* the immediate node after your checkbox.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation as well.